# javascript (reactJS) best way to access values in a child Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've got the following array:

[image]

This is an array of Users, and each User has an Attributes array.

Now I want to make a new array with users and only their attributes. Like this

```
users{
 0: {
    "phone_number",
    "email"
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?
thanks

Comment: instead of posting image, post sample data and the expected result to make your ques clear, also it will be easy for others to help you :)

Comment: I would map it to an object.....

Comment: @epascarello can you probably give an example?

Comment: Array reduce or array map and what you want as an output is not really valid..... So hard to help you when not sure what the output is actually supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need Array of users which contains arrays with users attributes, then you can use `Array.prototype.map` method:

```js
let users = [ 
    { Attributes: [ { Name: 'phone_number' }, { Name: 'email' } ] }, 
    { Attributes: [ { Name: 'phone_number1' }, { Name: 'email1' } ] }
];

let result = users.map((user) => user.Attributes.map((attr) => attr.Name));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: is it possible to store the values like this: `'email': value,`

Comment: Yes. Use this instead: `let result = users.map((user) => user.Attributes.reduce((res, attr) => {
    res[attr.Name] = attr.Value;

    return res;
  }, {})`